# HashMap accessible from whole project

Tags: java, spring

I have defined `HashMap`

```
<bean id="userMap" class="pl.test.pojo.UserMap">
    <property name="userMap">
        <map>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I want to be able to access this content from any class in my project
I write to it like:

```
@Autowired
UserMap userMap;
    Status s = new Status();
    User req = new User();
    s.setStatus(3);
    s.setErrorCode("0");
    s.setErrorDescription("OK");
    s.setCorrelationId(addToQuarantineRequest.getCorrelationId());
    userMap.getUserMap().put(req, s);
```

and it is ok, but from another class I want to read content of the `userMap` firstly declaring it with `@autowired` annotation I have got `NullPointerException` how can I make `Map` to be accesible from whole project?

Comment: getters and setters?

Comment: @JordiCastilla I don't quite understant. Class `UserMap` do have getters and setters. I don't knew if this have anything common with accesibility

Comment: NPE can occur when you haven't set Spring configs properly to use `Autowired`. Have you specified `<context:annotation-config/>` bit in your Spring xml config?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share among all the objects of your app a `Map` which is dynamically set, a simple way is to wrap the `Map` in a bean (like you actually do with the `UserMap` class) and declare this bean as a **singleton**. Each time you *wire* your wrapper class, you shall get the same instance, hence the same `Map` and be able to *share* the values. I would do something along:

```
public interface UserMap {
   void putStatus(User u, Status s);
   Status getStatus(User u);
}

public class UserMapImpl implements UserMap {
   Map<User, Status> statuses = new HashMap<>();

   public void putStatus(User u, Status s) {
      statuses.put(u, s);
   }

   public Status getStatus(User u) {
      statuses.get(u);
   }
}
```

Then if you are using XML configuration, you declare the bean as a *singleton*:

```
<bean id="userMap" class="pl.test.pojo.UserMapImpl" scope="singleton"/>
```

If you want to initialise the `Map` with keys/values you can do it in the bean (do you need that?).

And wherever you use this bean, either to put values or read ones, you can declare

```
public class Foo {
   @Autowired
   UserMap userMap;

   public void someMethod() {
      // put some data into userMap
   }
}

public class Bar {
   @Autowired
   UserMap userMap;

   public void someOtherMethod() {
      // read data from userMap
   }
}
```